# Add column of auto generated numbers to existing teradata table to use as key

Tags: teradata

I have an existing table where I need to add a "key" column and auto-populate that column with sequential numbers.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD key CHAR(25) 
key decimal(10,0) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 1 
            MAXVALUE 2147483647 
            NO CYCLE)
```

Can you help me structure this appropriately?

Comment: No way, you can't add an Identity column to an existing table in Teradata.

Comment: so it's not possible...hmmm okay - can I do it without identity? Just auto numbered?

Comment: No, why do you need it?

Comment: and can you explain more what identity does so I can make sure I understand it...

Comment: I need a unique identifier in an existing table.

Comment: Well, you should already have a Primary Key in that table :(

Comment: Thats what i am trying to add...unfortunately it doesn't have one

Comment: Create a new table with your identity column, and move the data to that table.